# ViewAnimator setting next view problem?

Tags: android, view

I'm using ViewAnimator to switch between views...

my layout file is like this:

```
        <ViewAnimator android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
        <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/List01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Flipper Content 0"></ExpandableListView>
        <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/List02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Flipper Content 0"></ExpandableListView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Flipper Content 2">
        </TextView>
    </ViewAnimator>
```

When I click on some of the children from the first expandable list I want to go directly to the third child.

```
    @Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    viewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(2);
    viewAnimator.showNext();

    return true;
}
```

Nothing happens when I click...

If I use only  `viewAnimator.showNext();` I get to the second element...

I cannot find out why it is not working for me.

Can someone give me a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem was that the second child's index is actually 1 (ViewAnimator uses 0-based indexes).